# One word to fill in any of the blanks

Tags: word

Here's one I remember from a while back.

There is one word that will fit into any of the blanks in the following sentence:

> __ I __ punched __ him __ in the __ eye __ yesterday __.

The meaning of the sentence will be different depending on where you place the word.  What is this word?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word is

> Only

But can be better explained here:

> https://www.humankinetics.com/flguideonweb/NitToPick16MisplacedOnly.htm

More explanation (provided, in part, by Will)

1. > ***Only* I punched him in the eye yesterday**: I was the only person who punched him Or Only, I punched him in the eye, yesterday.
2. > **I *only* punched him in the eye yesterday**: I didn't poke him in the eye OR I didn't poke *him* in the eye yesterday.
3. > **I punched *only* him in the eye yesterday**: I didn't punch anyone else in the eye
4. > **I punched him *only* in the eye yesterday**: I didn't punch him in the neck
5. > **I punched him in the *only* eye yesterday**: He has only one eye
6. > **I punched him in the eye *only* yesterday**: I punched him yesterday, which was recently OR I punched him in the eye, only, yesterday.
7. > **I punched him in the eye yesterday *only***: I punched him in the eye, but I only did it yesterday.  No other day.

Comment: I don't see how the meaning of 'I only punched him in the eye yesterday' is different from 'I punched him in the eye yesterday only'. They both indicate that yesterday was the only time it happened. Nevertheless, it's probably the right answer

Comment: The first means that you did nothing but punch him.  You didn't kick him, or spit on him.  The second means you punched him, but you only did it, yesterday.

Comment: Good on you for not jamming your thumbs in those sockets. If there's any distinction I take issue with it'd be "only yesterday" vs. "yesterday only."

Comment: Actually, I misread his comment and first and started to explain those two.  "Only yesterday" has two meanings, depending on comma usage.  The first is the same as "yesterday, only", but the other is "I punched him, but only in the eye."

Comment: ok, I guess the first means 'only in the eye, nowhere else'. But then, how does that differ from 'I punched him only in the eye yesterday'? If you take the last to mean 'him and nobody else', then that's the same as 'I punched only him in the eye yesterday'

Comment: "Only yesterday" implies that it was only yesterday, not that long ago.  "Yesterday only" means that it occurred yesterday, and at no other time.

Comment: Oh, and technically, there's one more place you could put the word, between "in" and "the", but it would have the same meaning as having it before "in", so I didn't put a blank there.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: A slight reworking of the sentence could add that extra distinction: "I saw Fred on the balconies yesterday"

Comment: @supercat - It actually can be placed almost anywhere in almost any sentence, if you think about it.  Some work better than others in terms of having distinct meanings based on where you put it...

Comment: I hope he deserved it, did he ask too many questions?

Comment: @Daedric ...[Only](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30961/one-word-to-fill-in-any-of-the-blanks) [one](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/images/articles/banners/122417.jpg)...

Comment: Incidentally, your alternate meanings for #1 and #6 both require the addition of punctuation (commas), which was not intended.  I didn't specifically forbid it, but it's not necessary to make them valid sentences, and also causes the meaning to overlap with other positions.